# How to establish connection between Magento 2 and some ERP Software?

Tags: api, rest-api, csv, magento-connect

I am working on ERP Magento 2 Connector. I have a query about it

How is it practical to make connection with some ERP through csv formate data. I mean we can create REST/SOAP APIs but how can we tell some ERP about the data coming. Whether from API or it is a CSV file, voice versa how Magento 2 gets response from ERP?

I have just started playing with APIs so any information will be quite helpful.

Here are some facts, I understood:

1. By default, M2 has just file import/Export ability in csv formate.
2. We can extend data sharing feature by using REST/SOAP APIs
3. We can create a module which will be a connecter between M2 and ERP.

Comment: It depends on the ERP you are using, which one is under your development?

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/frappe/erpnext its demo is here https://beta.erpnext.com If there is some other good free ERP available than this, pls suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how ErpNext works but as far as your concern, Magento 2 communicates with ERP via API, the connector allows the two way communication, you have to contact to ErpNext support to confirm whether they are offering Magento 2 or not. Your second concern, the CSV file, it depends how the developer developed the connector but by default it only communicates through API.